# Question migrated but Stack Overflow user has no Super User profile

Tags: discussion, migration, user-profiles, new-users

I just found this stackoverflow question migrated to superuser: [How to switch to user perspective in Blender](https://superuser.com/questions/446511/how-to-switch-to-user-perspective-in-blender/446653#446653)

It's OK so far but I see one little problem: The user has created an account at stackoverflow apparently to post that question and now there is no profile right here at the new site. I've answered the question but I am afraid that s/he will never get noticed about this answer especially in case of a brand new user who is not that familiar with Stack Exchange.

- Does the system send a notification about the answer in this case?
- Wouldn't it be better to migrate or copy the profile to the new Stack
  Exchange site where the question is hosted after moving? OK there are
  lots of pros and cons fighting each other about this approach, but I
  am concerned about detering new users from participating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All migrations are notified to the user. The user accounts are not created till the user explicitly logs in to the new site with the same Open ID that they had used on the other site.

When the user does login to the new user, the account association process takes place & the user's profile is 'reclaimed' - thus everything is automated.

Comment: It also should be noted that answers aren't always for the OP.  There are likely others out there with the same question that needs answering.

Comment: @KronoS - for others there's an autoredirect to the destination target.